# Is there a way to distinguish bad url (broken, not working) in python?

Tags: python

I have a list of urls and I want to check if any of these are working. I want to do this because I want to use google API to search within each of links, but when I run it I get the message "bad request", which seems to be because there are links that do not work within the list.

I couldn't go into all of the links, but for some of them I get message on google Chrome:

404. That’s an error.

The requested URL /playMsg.html was not found on this server.

Is there a way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Define what it means if a link is "not working" – 404? Malformed URL? Server doesn't respond? Some examples would be helpful

Comment: @qxz so when I enter the link, I get a message "bad request"

Comment: @qxz another message is "404. That’s an error.

The requested URL /playMsg.html was not found on this server."

Comment: Do it exactly like you're doing it: try to fetch the URL, and then examine the response status code. Every request to an HTTP server returns a status code. These are all documented. Start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: @BryanOakley Do you suggest import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://python.org/')
html = response.read()  and then find the error message?

Comment: there are many different libraries you can use. urllib2 is definitely one of them.

Comment: Use `try` and `except` to determine if the [link works, or doesn't](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/errors.html). Requests is a good external library too

Comment: @ClaytonWahlstrom I embedded in the code asking to search with google api, but doesnt seem to work :for i in range(0,k-1):
    try:
        queries = search_sources[i]
        res = service.cse().list(q= queries, cx='key',).execute()
    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
        print 'We failed with error code - %s.' % e.code

Answer (score 3):

This is simplified version of my code, that I use in some projects.

The logic is simple:

1. Send `url` to `server_response`
2. If status == 200 (`url` is valid) -> return `ok`
3. If status == 404, try to re-check the `url` 5 times every 10 secs (cover the case with bad connections)
4. If after 5 tries the status still 404 -> return `bad`

Want to mention, that this code does not cover other statuses (implement it yourself or change `if status == 404:` to `if status != 200:`)

```
import requests

from time import sleep


def server_response(url):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'}
    tries = 5

    while True:
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, stream=True)
        status = response.status_code

        if status == 404: # u can change it to 'if status != 200:' in order to cover all status codes except 200
            print('\n###################################')
            print('### THERE IS CONNECTION PROBLEM ###')
            print('Response code: %d \nURI: %s' % (status, url))
            print('###################################\n')
            sleep(10)
            tries -= 1

        elif status == 200:
            return 'ok'

        if tries == 0:
            return 'bad'


list_of_urls = ['www.site1.com', 'www.site2.com']

for url in list_of_urls:
    status = server_response(url)

    if status == 'ok':
        # do something
    else:
        # do something
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the suggestion. I've customized your code and tried running it but I get a response "status" not defined...as I understand we don't need to define it, what do you think is wrong?

Comment: @song0089, update your 1st post with customized code and mark somehow the line of error, then, I can help. You need to define `status` because 1) you need to check the code 200/404 (in function) and 2) check if the `url` is `ok` or `bad` (in the block `for url in list_of_urls:`). Sometimes `not defined` can occur because of wrong indentation

Comment: @song0089, I would appreciate if you could accept the answer (under the 2 up\down arrows in front of my answer there is a grey check mark). Thank you.